# error en nettbeans con java : A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again ? no entiendo

Tags: java, netbeans

mi codigo (primera vez que uso java):

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Main.java to edit this template
 */
package java.introduction;

/**
 *
 * @author Samantha
 */
public class JavaIntroduction {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Samantha";
        System.out.println(name);
        
        int number = 19;
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

```
run:
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.introduction
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:896)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1011)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:475)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:790)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:685)
C:\Users\Samantha\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\18\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Samantha\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\18\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Estoy aprendiendo a usar java y quise imprimir unas variables y me sale ese error y no se que significa.

Answer (score 1):

El error dice claramente (entre otras cosas)

> java.lang.SecurityException: **Prohibited package name**: java.introduction

(El resaltado es mío).

Esto significa que no puedes usar el nombre de paquete `java.introduction`, en la línea:

```
package java.introduction;
```

Esto es porque no puedes utilizar `java.` para nombrar tus paquetes.
Te recomiendo leer las recomendaciones de la documentación oficial: [Naming a Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) (en inglés).

En resúmen, mientras no estés trabajando para una compañía, si tienes que declarar el paquete, puedes utilizar un *dominio ejemplo* o *inventado* para nombrar tus paquetes, siempre que no utilices un nombre que sea de una compañía conocida. Si tienes un dominio personal, puedes utilizar el mismo y no debiera darte problema, por ejemplo, yo utilizaría:

```
package com.wordpress.jachguate.introduction;
package com.ejemplo.jachguate.introduction;
```

Si ves, en el primero utilizo un sub-dominio que está bajo mi control y en el segundo simplemente inventé el nombre, y le agrego mi *nickname* para intentar que no haya otro nombre con el mismo paquete.

También puedes omitir la línea que declara el paquete al que pertenece (la que inicia con `package`), y en ese caso la clase pertenecerá al llamado *paquete default*.